# SQL Server stored procedure: verify CRUD operation success/failure using output variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, try-catch

I am trying to create a SQL Server stored procedure to handle updates to a table using some dynamic SQL. The table name required for the update is stored in a table that correlates a table id to a category id. Once the table name is retrieved and the table id is not null, I update the table using a dynamic SQL query as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EBS_CustomForms_SetCategoryData] 
    (@flag int output,
     @cat_id int, 
     @sort int, 
     @value varchar(50), 
     @active int, 
     @enum int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tbl as varchar(50)
    DECLARE @tbl_id as int
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    BEGIN TRY
        SET @tbl_id = (SELECT [tbl_id] 
                       FROM [demodata].[dbo].[ebscustomforms_cattable] 
                       WHERE cat_id = @cat_id)

        IF @tbl_id IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            SET @tbl = (SELECT table_name 
                        FROM ebscustomforms_enumtable 
                        WHERE tbl_id = @tbl_id)
            SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tbl + ' SET [sort_order] = @sort, [value] = @value, [active] = @active WHERE [enum_id] = @enum'

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@sort int, @value varchar(50), @active int, @enum int', @sort, @value, @active, @enum

            SET @flag = 0

            RETURN @flag
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @flag = 1;
            RETURN @flag
        END
    END CATCH
END
```

I want this stored procedure to return an int value indicating whether the stored procedure was successful (0) or failed (1) updating the table.

Points of error are as follows:

1. `@tbl_id` variable is null
2. `@tbl` is either null or an empty varchar
3. The table to be updated does not have a record `where [enum_id] = @enum`

I have noticed that when I try to update a record that does not exist, the procedure seems to return as successful i.e. @flag = 0. However, I would imagine that an error should be thrown because the record does not exist.

Comment: The return value of a procedure is an int. It is used to indicate the status of the execution. Since you correctly have defined @flag as OUTPUT you should simply remove your RETURN statements. You also should consider changing the SP_ prefix (or even better, removing the prefix entirely) from your procedure name. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I changed the variable type to int. Thank you for pointing out that mistake.

Comment: All you need to do from here is remove the return statements and you should be good to go.

Comment: I removed the RETURN statements as you've mentioned however, the procedure is still not catching errors. I have tested it with a scenario that should assert a '@flag' value of 1 (trying to update a table that does not have a record where [enum_id] = '@enum'). In this scenario, @flag is not set. I do not think it is catching the error.

Comment: Updating a table where there are no rows updated is NOT an error. Earlier you were setting your flag variable to @@rowcount. Why did you remove that? That would tell you how many rows were affected...and if there weren't any your flag value would be 0.